# What is the red promot mean in time Profiler

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

In Xcode's Instruments，I open the time Profiler to text my App, However,I found some of the code's promot is yellow,and some is red. as the picture showing.

why some methods is yellow and some is red? the yellow promot spend 5 ms but it is yellow,and the other spend only 1 ms but it is a red promot? can someone tell me what is it mean?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876570/red-line-in-instruments